# How can I call a SELECT procedure from Visual Studio using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle, visual-studio

I'm a beginner at developing web applications using C# language and I'm facing a problem with running my ASP.NET code. I've written a a procedure in TOAD FOR ORACLE and it created successfully.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GENERALAPPLICATION.LE_SELECT_EMPLOYEE 
(EMPID IN OUT INTEGER, F_NAME OUT VARCHAR, L_NAME OUT VARCHAR, 
 PHO OUT INTEGER, ADRS OUT VARCHAR)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       FNAME, LNAME, PHONE, ADDRESS 
    INTO 
       F_NAME, L_NAME, PHO, ADRS 
    FROM 
       LE_EMPLOYEE
    WHERE 
       EID = EMPID;
   COMMIT;

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END LE_SELECT_EMPLOYEE;
/
```

Now I want to use it in a web application form using C#, so I wrote this code in a button click handler method:

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int EID = int.Parse(EIDBox.Text);

    string oradb = "Data Source=*****;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Unicode=True";

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("LE_SELECT_EMPLOYEE", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("EMPID", OracleType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.InputOutput.ToString()).Value = EID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("F_NAME", OracleType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Output.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("L_NAME", OracleType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Output.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("PHO", OracleType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Output.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ADRS", OracleType.VarChar, 20, ParameterDirection.Output.ToString());

    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    dr.Read();

    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DT.Load(dr);

    GridView1.DataSource = DT;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

but I get an error on the line

```
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

saying that there is a wrong number of types of arguments in call to.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException' occurred in System.Data.OracleClient.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to " the error.

Would you please help me to find the reason that causes this problem? Thank you.

Comment: PHO OUT INTEGER, and you passed the "PHO", OracleType.VarChar, Please change it to integer.

Comment: oh yeah, i changed it now to "  cmd.Parameters.Add("PHO", OracleType.Number, (int)ParameterDirection.Output).ToString();   " but i still got the same error

Comment: {"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'LE_SELECT_EMPLOYEE'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n"}

Comment: EMPID also integer and you passed the varchar. Error region parameter name might be misspelled, a parameter might have the wrong datatype, the declaration might be faulty, or the declaration might be placed incorrectly in the block structure.

Comment: i pars it up by using int EID = int.Parse(EIDBox.Text); @SainPradeep

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Oracle and C# is that all data must be returned using a cursor. Whether you are returning one value or a table full you must use a SYS_REFCURSOR.

Here is your code rewritten to do that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GENERALAPPLICATION.LE_SELECT_EMPLOYEE 
(EMPID_IN IN NUMBER v_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
v_selectquery   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   v_selectquery = 'SELECT FNAME, LNAME, PHONE, ADDRESS '
    ||'FROM LE_EMPLOYEE WHERE EID ='|| EMPID_IN;

   OPEN v_cursor FOR v_selectquery;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          THEN
             v_selectquery := 'Select null from dual';

             OPEN v_cursor FOR v_selectquery;
END LE_SELECT_EMPLOYEE;
```